# How to specify argument in CREATE_FUNC in Coco2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

My `MessageBoxes` class has an argument passed in the constructor, I hope to know how can I specify the argument, which is `std::string _content` in this context, in the `CREATE_FUNC()`?

The error I get says "constructors cannot be declared 'static'"

This is the code of **MessageBoxes.h:**

```
class MessageBoxes : public cocos2d::Node
{
    private:
        Sprite* _sprite;
        bool _speaking;
        float _speakingTime;
        std::string _content;
    public:
        CREATE_FUNC(MessageBoxes(std::string content)); 

    protected:
        virtual bool init(std::string _content);
        void setSprite();
        void setContent();
};
```

Comment: @VictorPolevoy thanks for the reminder...Fixed!

Comment: What errors do you have at the `CREATE_FUNC(` line?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy updated in the question

Comment: Don't put it in the code snippet, write it like does compiler say under the code snippet.

Comment: please, look how the error messages are written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408667/libxsd-and-gcc-4-9-1) and try to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE_FUNC is a predefined macros defined in CCPlatformMacros.h

```
#define CREATE_FUNC(__TYPE__) \
static __TYPE__* create() \
{ \
    __TYPE__ *pRet = new(std::nothrow) __TYPE__(); \
    if (pRet && pRet->init()) \
    { \
        pRet->autorelease(); \
        return pRet; \
    } \
    else \
    { \
        delete pRet; \
        pRet = NULL; \
        return NULL; \
    } \
}
```

the code

> CREATE_FUNC(MessageBoxes(std::string content));

actually is

```
new(std::nothrow) MessageBoxes(std::string content)();
```

which has compile error in c++.

but you can write the create funtion similar to CREATE_FUNC by yourself, like

```
static MessageBoxes* create(std::string content) {
    MessageBoxes* ret = new(std::nothrow) MessageBoxes();
    if(ret && ret->init(content)) { //<----Or anything you wanna init with
        ret->autorelease();
        return ret;
    } else {
        delete ret;
        ret = nullptr;
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, yeah some little error in the code you provided though